# Should I disable the trigger?

Tags: sql-server, database-trigger

I have a trigger that audits changes to its table into the corresponding history table.
However, I need to add a new column to the table and then populate it with data.
Do I need to temporarily disable the trigger while populating the column?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want your changes audited? Do you care about performance if you don't want it audited? And do you think the trigger needs updating to capture this new column into the audit table? (note it would fire regardless).

Comment: It is just a DML trigger. I am not sure it should just audit the user's operations or all the changes. To me, such changes are just like an initial setting. I may choose not to audit these changes but I am not sure.

Comment: then the choice seems to be up to you, if you want them included in the audit.

Answer (score 0):

This completely depends on your needs and how the trigger is written and how the history is maintained..
But however in general, the new column addition will not be reflected unless you do changes to thetrigger(at times the history table too). So disabling trigger temporarily will not have much impact.

I would suggest to lock the table while you insert new column, populate the column and then release the lock ,also do modification to trigger to accommodate the new column now

Comment: if the trigger modification is done before the data is edited, then disabling the trigger could have a huge impact on performance.

Comment: Yes, i suggest to do modification to trigger only after the new column is poplated..since the values is populated manully we dont wish it to be recorded in history..might be we coluld add one item in audit history like this changes was done by this user,on date, purpose and so on..so it is completely the OP decision and his scenario